# Using service.ts variables on multiple components

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I've set up next.service.ts with 3 variables (user, action, rest) and made setters(updateNext()) and getters (getUser, getAction, getRest). I've got to use the setter to change the variables in one component (stock-management component) and retrieved these variables in another component (inventory-record component) but I can't seem to retrieve them from another component (inventory-record-filled component).

I've tried returning a string ("TEST") in the getter and it worked, but when I tried returning a variable, it just returned nothing/empty string.

```
export class NextService {
  private action: string;
  private user: string;
  private restraunt: string;

  constructor() { }

  updateNext(actions, users, restraunts) {
    this.action = actions;
    this.user = users;
    this.restraunt = restraunts;
  }

  getAction(): string {
    return this.action;
  }

  getUser(): string {
    return this.user;
  }

  getRest(): string {
    return this.restraunt;
  }
```

```
export class InventoryRecordComponent implements OnInit {
  name = '';
  rest = '';
  action = '';

  constructor(private next: NextService) {
    this.name = this.next.getUser();
    this.action = this.next.getAction();
    this.rest = this.next.getRest();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    document.getElementById('dne').style.display = 'none';
  }

  onSubmit(f: NgForm) {
    const x = document.getElementById('dne');
    if (!this.next.updateCode(this.code)) {
      x.style.display = 'block';
      f.resetForm();
    } else {
      this.next.updateCode(this.code);
      location.replace('inventory-record/qty');
    }
  }
}
```

```
export class InventoryRecordFilledComponent implements OnInit {
  name: string;
  action: string;
  rest: string;

  constructor(private next: NextService) {
    this.name = this.next.getUser();
    this.action = this.next.getAction();
    this.rest = this.next.getRest();
   }

  ngOnInit() {

  }
}
```

Each component have its respective html files with

{{ name }} {{ action }} {{ rest }}

Answer (score 0):

If you need your component to behave as a Simpleton (where it contains the same values regardless of where in the application it is used) you must set its `providedIn` value to `"root"`, like so:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class NextService {
  // The rest of the code stays the same
}
```

The description for that can be found here: https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services#providing-a-singleton-service

If you don't do that, each component that imports `NextService` will have it's own instance of `NextService`, with its own isolated values. If you want the values of a service to be available everywhere that the service is used in, then you want the service to be a Simpleton, so you must follow the steps.

Following the steps above is not the only way to make your component a Simpleton, but as the link mentions, it is the preferred way to do that.

Hope that helps!

Comment: thank you for your response, but the service already has the "providedIn: 'root' " statement and I've also made sure to add this service to the providers array so I'm not really sure what's going on.

Comment: Do `InventoryRecordComponent` and `InventoryRecordFilledComponent` exist at the same time? Is it possible that `InventoryRecordFilledComponent` is getting the values of the service before `InventoryRecordComponent` has set them to the new values? If so, I think it would be a better idea to set the `name`, `action`, and `rest` variables to Observables - that way you can push a new value when calling `updateCode`, and subscribe to those values inside of the classes so that they are updated when a new value is pushed.

Comment: As you've said, I made name, action, and rest into observables and subscribed to them inside each component. It worked flawlessly on the inventory-record component. However, the inventory-record-filled component again just returns the default data instead of the updated data.

Comment: Could you post a demo on StackBlitz? My next recommendation would be to make the variables into [Behavior Subjects](https://alligator.io/rxjs/subjects/#behavior-subjects), but I'm not 100% sure. I'd be able to give you a more informed answer with a demo. Also, I should have recommended that you turn the variables into [Subjects](https://alligator.io/rxjs/subjects/)  instead since you would have to push values into them, which Observables don't allow you to do.